# Difference between "mark" and "marker"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

In a diagram, I added small visual elements to identify specific objects. Should I call these things *(visual) marks* or *(visual) markers*? What is the difference? Is there a better term?

According to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/) a *mark* is a [*a visible impression or trace on something*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mark?s=t) and a *marker* is [*something used as a mark or indication*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/marker?s=t). However, this does not answer my question because the definition of *marker* is somehow self-referencing: is something used as a mark a *mark* or a *marker*?

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: According to dictionary.com a "mark" is a "a visible impression or trace on something" and "marker" is "something used as a mark or indication". That doesn't help either.

Comment: Please add the definitions to your question and link to their source. Then, clarify why neither of them is suitable.

Comment: I just edited the question as proposed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A *mark* is a visible impression or trace on something (as you found).

A *marker* is a mark with a specific meaning. For example, it can apply to a blob of paint indicating a part has been inspected: the blob is a mark, but its specific meaning turns it into a marker.

Your marks have a specific purpose to identify the various objects. Thus they are markers.

Comment: Yes, in the biomed world, _markers_ are signs of a particular kind of cancer, cancer in general, or some other chronic or acute-but-transient disease.

Comment: And in gambling circles - or at least in Damon Runyon's stories set in these circles - a *marker* is a promise to pay a gambling loss, or the collateral for the debt.